# SQL query group by with extra column

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have been trying to create an sql query that returns the most recent record for each user on a given day.

```
Select dbfirst, dblast, max(dbdate) as MaxDate 
from table 
where (DATEPART(yy, dbdate) = 2015 
  AND DATEPART(mm, dbdate) = 10 
  AND DATEPART(dd, dbdate) = 22) 
group by dbfirst, dblast
```

The results I get back are for users that have signed in on that given day ie.

```
╔═════════╦════════╦════════════════════════╗
║ dbfirst ║ dblast ║   MaxDate              ║
╠═════════╬════════╬════════════════════════╣
║ user    ║     10 ║ 20151022 13:13:09.000  ║
║ user    ║     11 ║ 20151022 10:18:50.000  ║
╚═════════╩════════╩════════════════════════╝
```

This returns only one record for a user which is the most current.

I also need to be able to display the column 'dbflow' in the results which is a varchar "In" or "Out" but when I do this.

```
Select  dbfirst, dblast, dbflow, max(dbdate) as MaxDate from [Inventory].[dbo].[pr_dbs] where (DATEPART(yy, dbdate) = 2015 AND DATEPART(mm, dbdate) = 10 AND DATEPART(dd, dbdate) = 22) group by dbfirst, dblast, dbflow
```

It returns the newest In and Out and I just need the latest record regardless of dbflow.

```
╔═════════╦════════╦════════╦═════════════════════════╗
║ dbfirst ║ dblast ║ dbflow ║ MaxDate                 ║
╠═════════╬════════╬════════╬═════════════════════════╣
║ user    ║ 10     ║ In     ║ 2015-10-22 13:13:09.000 ║
║ user    ║ 11     ║ In     ║ 2015-10-22 10:18:50.000 ║
║ user    ║ 10     ║ Out    ║ 2015-10-22 12:13:09.000 ║
║ user    ║ 11     ║ Out    ║ 2015-10-22 9:18:50.000  ║
╚═════════╩════════╩════════╩═════════════════════════╝
```

Thanks in advance for your assistance or advice.

Comment: Which DBMS do you use?

Comment: Unrelated but: why do you make the comparison with `dbdate` so complicated? why not simply use: `where dbdate = '20151022'`

Comment: The question makes no sense. Do `max(dbflow)`

Comment: If you have 2 records with the same `dbfirst` and `dblast` but different `dbflow` which one do you want to show? (And that's the point of aggregation!)

Comment: I use the complicated way of checking the date as the value in the database is date and time and I need to check any record that is entered that day.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to the official **Microsoft Training Kit Book for Exam 70-461** (SQL Server), you have 3 workaround for your problem (if you know that there can’t be more than one distinct dbflow per each
distinct (dbfirst, dblast)):

1. Just add it to the `GROUP BY` clause
2. The 2nd option is to apply an aggregate function like `MAX` to the column.
3. The 3rd option is to group and aggregate the rows from the [pr_dbs] table first, define a table expression based on the grouped query, and then join the table expression with the [pr_dbs] original table to get the last column

:

```
WITH CTE AS (
SELECT dbfirst, dblast, max(dbdate) as MaxDate 
     FROM [Inventory].[dbo].[pr_dbs]
     WHERE (DATEPART(yy, dbdate) = 2015 
     AND DATEPART(mm, dbdate) = 10 
     AND DATEPART(dd, dbdate) = 22) 
     GROUP BY dbfirst, dblast
 )
 SELECT CTE.*, D.dbflow
 FROM [Inventory].[dbo].[pr_dbs] AS D
      INNER JOIN CTE
      ON D.dblast = CTE.dblast
      AND D.dbfirst = CTE.dbfirst;
```

> SQL Server usually optimizes the third solution like it does the
>   first. The first solution might be preferable because it involves much
>   less code.

**EDIT:**

As you precised your question, does it fill your need:

```
SELECT table.dbfirst, table.dblast, table.MaxDate, table.dbflow
FROM table 
    INNER JOIN 
    (
        SELECT dbfirst, dblast, max(dbdate) as MaxDate 
        FROM table
        WHERE (DATEPART(yy, dbdate) = 2015 
        AND DATEPART(mm, dbdate) = 10 
        AND DATEPART(dd, dbdate) = 22)
        GROUP BY dbfirst, dblast
    ) AS T
    ON table.dbfirst = T.dbfirst
    AND table.dblast = T.dblast
    AND table.dbdate = T.MaxDate
```

Comment: I still get the most recent In and Out and not just the most recent for a given person (dbfirst, dblast)

Comment: Okay I have looked back at the table and you are 100% correct. Thank you ever so much

Comment: You're welcome :). Do not forget to mark the answer as Resolved then.

Answer (score 1):

Have you thought of using windowed functions? This would be example for your query:

```
SELECT DISTINCT dbflow
    , dbfirst
    , dblast
    , MAX(dbdate) OVER (PARTITION BY dbfirst, dblast) AS MaxDate
FROM [Inventory].[dbo].[pr_dbs]
WHERE DATEPART(yy, dbdate) = 2015
    AND DATEPART(mm, dbdate) = 10
    AND DATEPART(dd, dbdate) = 22;
```

However I'm not certain if this is correct logic.

Answer (score 0):

Don't use date parts for the comparison.  The use of functions generally precludes the use of indexes.  So, one possibility for your query is:

```
Select dbfirst, dblast, max(dbdate) as MaxDate, AVG(dbflow)
from table 
where dbdate >= '2015-10-22' and dbdate < '2015-10-23'
group by dbfirst, dblast;
```

If you want the last flow on the date, then use window functions with no aggregation:

```
Select dbfirst, dblast, dbdate as MaxDate, dbflow
from (select t.*,
             row_number() over (order by dbdate desc) as seqnum
      from table t
      where dbdate >= '2015-10-22' and dbdate < '2015-10-23'
     ) t
where seqnum = 1;
```

Both of these queries can take advantage of an index on `table(dbdate)`, which your version cannot.

Answer (score -1):

You show one result line per `dbfirst` and `dblast` and want to show `dbflow` for them. But which one? There are several records per `dbfirst` and `dblast`, which is why you cannot show `dbdate`, but decide for one date, i.e. `max(dbdate)`.

As with the date, you must decide which `dbflow` to show and use MAX, MIN, AVG, or whatever accordingly.